# open one sql express db in multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-express

I would like access a sql express db in multiple projects, a dynamic data project to administrate the data and a console application which fetches the data from the db, is there an option to do this? or should I use a SQL CE for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from simply adding a connection string to the database in both projects?

Comment: no, but I would like to open the database as a local file and when I try to access the db through the console app, it fails saying a database with the same name is open already

Answer (score 1):

A database is meant to be accessed from different clients. You can specify the same connection string in both projects, Dynamic Data and Console. SQL Server Express will handle traffic from both over the network easily.

You *can* use different data access strategies as well, in both projects. LINQ To SQL, DIY ADO, SubSonic, etc.